# Predict class label at time t given time-series of vectors up to time t

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, classification

Given a series of $k=4$ vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^n$), with $n=70$ at time $t=-3$, ..., $t=0$, and class labels for vectors at $t=-3$, ..., $t=-1$. Which machine learning approach would be best for predicting the class label at $t=0$?

Comment: Which single approach would be best seems a very hard thing for someone to tell you if they can't see your data! Would you be content for someone to tell you what options you have rather than which is "best"? Can you say anything about the time dependency of your data?

Comment: I added n=70 if that helps. I tried stacking up the four vectors in a new vector in $\mathbb{R}^{4n}$. Are there any more sophisticated approaches than this? I guess something like neural networks don't make sense since I only care about the previous 3 datapoints.